# Angular Js Clear Form

Tags: angularjs, forms

After filling all mandatory field of form submit button is Enable.

When i clear the form all date is clearing but submit button Still Enable.

**Here is myForm :**

```
**<form id="payment-form" name="creditPaymentForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cardcno" ng-minlength="15" required="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cardcvv" ng-minlength="3" required="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cardexp" ng-minlength="6" required="">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()" ng-disabled="creditPaymentForm.$invalid">Submit</button>**
    <button type="reset"  ng-click="creditPaymentForm.$setPristine();">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Comment: remove `$scope`  from ng-click on clear

Comment: Tried That, Still Coming as Valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workine fine for me

i have also intialize the values in the controller like this

```
  $scope.cardcno = "";
  $scope.cardcvv = "";
  $scope.cardexp = "";
```

Here is a working fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ag9pqvgg/)

Comment: You are Right, we should not user ` $scope.creditPaymentForm = {}; `, its making the complete Object Empty